# How can I put into javascript function on .js file a php value from a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Maps API with random coordinates but I don't know and I need some information how can I put into javascript function on .js file a php value from a php file?. For example if we have the several codes:

1) API code to generate a route between 2 coordinates(order2.js):

```
(function() {
window.onload = function() {
// Creating a map
var options = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.3834, -70.6),
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
// Creating an array that will contain the points for the polyline
var route = [
new google.maps.LatLng(-33.02644,-71.539775),
new google.maps.LatLng(-33.605148,-70.702197)
];
// Creating the polyline object
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: route,
strokeColor: "#ff0000",
strokeOpacity: 0.6,
strokeWeight: 5
});
// Adding the polyline to the map
polyline.setMap(map);
};
})();
```

2) Google Maps Api code to show(map2.html):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Chapter 4 - Google Maps API 3</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/graphic.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/order2.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
 <input type="button" value="getValues" id="getValues" />
 <input type="button" value="changeValues" id="changeValues" />
 <div id="map"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

3)If I have the next float random code(random.php):

```
<?php

    while($x <= 2995 and $y <= 71333)
    {
    $x = rand(2025,2995);
    $y = rand(70116,71333);
    $w = $x/100;
    $z = $y/1000;
    echo $w."<br>".$z."<br>";    
}    

?>
```

Now in basis to before codes I'm really need to know:

How can I to transfer $w and $z values  from random.php to any function(a,b) related with order2.js ?

Thanks by your useful help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1) if its only for creating random numbers, you can easily do that with javascript.

2) if it's really important to get data from php, the best way is to create a textarea that is hidden from the end user.

in the textarea place all the data you want to transfer to the js files in JSON format!
something like this:

```
<textarea id="phpData" style="display:none">{"J":5,"test2":"N"}</textarea>
```

now if you would like to access it from js:

```
var thePhpData = JSON.parse( $("#phpData").val() );
```

to get values:

```
 thePhpData.J
 thePhpData.test2
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is that you have to include your JavaScript into a PHP file...

Order2.php

```
<?php
include("random.php");

echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>

function(){
...
// to use the values in its place
".$w." .... ".$z."
}
";

</script>

?>
```

.... are other codes